# Add image at end of word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have created a `userform` in Excel where people fill in certain information and at the press of a button it creates a word document.

This all works fine but I also included the option to add pictures to that word document, so at a certain point people can select a picture.

The file path for these pictures are put in an array and after all information in the the `userform` has been added to the word document, the pictures need to be added. This works as well but for some reason they are added at the top of the document, rather than at the bottom. Is there any way I can specify I want it added at the bottom?

The code I have right now is:

```
Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

With wrdDoc

For i = 1 To UBound(ImageArr)
        .InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:=ImageArr(i)      
Next i
```

Comment: See [documentation from Microsoft .InlineShape.AddPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture) to set picture place.

Answer (score 0):

When adding content to a Word document it's a good idea to specify a specific target `Range`. That's a complex topic and there's often more than one option for creating a `Range`...

But for getting the end of a document I usually use:

```
Dim rngEndOfDoc as Range
Set rngEndOfDoc = wrdDoc.Content
rngEndOfDoc.Collapse(0)  'Word enumeration: wdCollapseEnd
```

Then add the picture

```
wrdDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:=ImageArr(i), Range:=rngEndOfDoc
```